# How do I approach crashes where there is no sign of my own code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

E.g. I have this trace.

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x32fe2df0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x33062c97 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x32f81939 abort + 76
3  libc++abi.dylib                0x3217fbbd __cxa_bad_cast
4  libc++abi.dylib                0x3219966f default_terminate_handler() + 266
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x32973f11 _objc_terminate() + 192
```

or this

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2d60eab8 __CFBasicHashDeallocate + 48
1  CoreFoundation                 0x2d52488f CFRelease + 462
2  QuartzCore                     0x2fa8d635 CA::release_objects(X::List<void const*>*) + 16
3  QuartzCore                     0x2fa8cec7 CA::Layer::~Layer() + 242
4  QuartzCore                     0x2fa8e431 CA::release_root_if_unused(CA::Layer*, CA::Layer*, void*) + 48
5  QuartzCore                     0x2fa8e3ad x_hash_table_remove_if + 68
6  QuartzCore                     0x2fa89443 CA::Transaction::commit() + 142
7  UIKit                          0x2fe0940b _afterCACommitHandler + 126
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2d5bf255 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
9  CoreFoundation                 0x2d5bcbf9 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 284
10 CoreFoundation                 0x2d5bcf3b __CFRunLoopRun + 730
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2d527ebf CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
12 CoreFoundation                 0x2d527ca3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
13 GraphicsServices               0x3244e663 GSEventRunModal + 138
14 UIKit                          0x2fe7414d UIApplicationMain + 1136
15 myapp                          0x0009c6f3 main (main.m:6)
```

or this

```
Thread : Crashed: WebThread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x31ea0f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x272eeea1 +[UIViewAnimationState popAnimationState] + 320
2  MediaPlayer                    0x2563056b -[MPVolumeSlider _layoutForAvailableRoutes] + 1410
3  MediaPlayer                    0x2562f1b5 -[MPVolumeSlider layoutSubviews] + 60
4  UIKit                          0x272ba7ff -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 514
5  QuartzCore                     0x26ce0835 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 136
6  QuartzCore                     0x26cdc20d CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
7  UIKit                          0x272ccf77 -[UIView(Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 138
8  UIKit                          0x272d2463 -[UISlider setValue:animated:] + 178
9  MediaPlayer                    0x2562f8ab -[MPVolumeSlider volumeController:volumeValueDidChange:] + 78
10 MediaPlayer                    0x2569391d -[MPVolumeController updateVolumeValue] + 252
11 MediaPlayer                    0x2562f2c3 -[MPVolumeSlider didMoveToSuperview] + 126
12 UIKit                          0x272b9721 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 428
13 UIKit                          0x272c3bcf -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1462
14 UIKit                          0x272c360f -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 30
15 MediaPlayer                    0x25632099 -[MPVolumeView _createSubviews] + 236
16 MediaPlayer                    0x25630ce5 -[MPVolumeView _initWithStyle:] + 212
17 MediaPlayer                    0x25630d79 -[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:style:] + 80
18 MediaPlayer                    0x25630d23 -[MPVolumeView initWithFrame:] + 38
19 UIKit                          0x272da3a1 -[UIView init] + 44
20 WebCore                        0x2fdcd1cf -[WebMediaSessionHelper initWithCallback:] + 178
21 WebCore                        0x2fdcc611 WebCore::MediaSessionManageriOS::MediaSessionManageriOS() + 172
22 WebCore                        0x2fdcc4fd WebCore::MediaSessionManager::sharedManager() + 124
23 WebCore                        0x2fdcb785 WebCore::MediaSession::MediaSession(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 32
24 WebCore                        0x2fa5fe75 WebCore::HTMLMediaSession::create(WebCore::MediaSessionClient&) + 20
25 WebCore                        0x2fa4e81f WebCore::HTMLMediaElement::HTMLMediaElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 1046
26 WebCore                        0x2fa77917 WebCore::HTMLVideoElement::create(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, bool) + 38
27 WebCore                        0x2fa41b79 WebCore::videoConstructor(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 56
28 WebCore                        0x2fa412cd WebCore::HTMLElementFactory::createElement(WebCore::QualifiedName const&, WebCore::Document&, WebCore::HTMLFormElement*, bool) + 232
29 WebCore                        0x2f64b53d WebCore::HTMLDocument::createElement(WTF::AtomicString const&, int&) + 88
30 WebCore                        0x2f64b47f WebCore::jsDocumentPrototypeFunctionCreateElement(JSC::ExecState*) + 242
31 JavaScriptCore                 0x2521d783 llint_entry + 21314
32 JavaScriptCore                 0x2521d377 llint_entry + 20278
33 JavaScriptCore                 0x2521d377 llint_entry + 20278
34 JavaScriptCore                 0x2521d377 llint_entry + 20278
35 JavaScriptCore                 0x2521822f callToJavaScript + 334
36 JavaScriptCore                 0x251a7d09 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 36
37 JavaScriptCore                 0x24fde3fb JSC::Interpreter::execute(JSC::ProgramExecutable*, JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*) + 5738
38 JavaScriptCore                 0x24fdcc43 JSC::evaluate(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::SourceCode const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::JSValue*) + 358
39 WebCore                        0x2fefd539 WebCore::ScriptController::evaluateInWorld(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&, WebCore::DOMWrapperWorld&) + 196
40 WebCore                        0x2f666173 WebCore::ScriptController::evaluate(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 26
41 WebCore                        0x2f666117 WebCore::ScriptElement::executeScript(WebCore::ScriptSourceCode const&) + 234
42 WebCore                        0x2f6ecb05 WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::executePendingScriptAndDispatchEvent(WebCore::PendingScript&) + 156
43 WebCore                        0x2f6e8059 WebCore::HTMLScriptRunner::executeParsingBlockingScripts() + 244
44 WebCore                        0x2f6e576d WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::runScriptsForPausedTreeBuilder() + 52
45 WebCore                        0x2f68dd77 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::canTakeNextToken(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode, WebCore::PumpSession&) + 50
46 WebCore                        0x2f68d305 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::pumpTokenizer(WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::SynchronousMode) + 344
47 WebCore                        0x2f6edf3f WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::resumeParsingAfterScriptExecution() + 78
48 WebCore                        0x2f672c1d WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::executeScriptsWaitingForStylesheets() + 44
49 WebCore                        0x2f66ff7b WebCore::Document::didRemoveAllPendingStylesheet() + 66
50 WebCore                        0x2f738151 WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::sheetLoaded() + 76
51 WebCore                        0x2f66fe93 WebCore::StyleSheetContents::checkLoaded() + 130
52 WebCore                        0x2fa4d415 WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::setCSSStyleSheet(WTF::String const&, WebCore::URL const&, WTF::String const&, WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet const*) + 508
53 WebCore                        0x2f6ee08b WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet::checkNotify() + 246
54 WebCore                        0x2f737a79 WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet::finishLoading(WebCore::ResourceBuffer*) + 192
55 WebCore                        0x2f6e9893 WebCore::SubresourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 78
56 CFNetwork                      0x2380df5f ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic26_delegate_didFinishLoadingEU13block_pointerFvvE_block_invoke + 78
57 CFNetwork                      0x238aaff9 ___ZN27URLConnectionClient_Classic18_withDelegateAsyncEPKcU13block_pointerFvP16_CFURLConnectionPK33CFURLConnectionClientCurrent_VMaxE_block_invoke_2 + 60
58 CFNetwork                      0x237fed8d RunloopBlockContext::_invoke_block(void const*, void*) + 60
59 CoreFoundation                 0x23cb1e1d CFArrayApplyFunction + 36
60 CFNetwork                      0x237fec47 RunloopBlockContext::perform() + 182
61 CFNetwork                      0x237feb0d MultiplexerSource::perform() + 216
62 CFNetwork                      0x237fe9a1 MultiplexerSource::_perform(void*) + 48
63 CoreFoundation                 0x23d66fbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
64 CoreFoundation                 0x23d663cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
65 CoreFoundation                 0x23d64a35 __CFRunLoopRun + 772
66 CoreFoundation                 0x23cb23b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
67 CoreFoundation                 0x23cb21c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
68 WebCore                        0x2f6a9483 RunWebThread(void*) + 418
69 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x32567e23 _pthread_body + 138
70 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x32567d97 _pthread_start + 118
```

How can I go about to solve these?

Comment: Do you get no errors? Does it just crash randomly? What exactly are you doing to get these crashes? Have you tried using Exception breakpoints?

Comment: I think these reports are from iTunes or something similar. What you might find interesting would be: atos and dwarfdump commands. These can greatly help you symbolicate your crash report

Comment: Actually these traces are from Crashlytics so I have no idea what the user did to have the app crash.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said something similar. If you have .dSYM file you can use mentioned commands to resolve addresses into exact location in the code.

Comment: @NickCatib A late response, but thanks. :) I still haven't managed to get the data as dwarfdump can't find the crash address I'm specifying. It's looking in .debug_info/frame, but my logs are in Fabric.io ...

Comment: Did you ever manage to track these down?

Comment: @andygeers No, unfortunately not. I've since moved on to other projects and try to correlate this with releases to help figure out cause and effect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also seeing the crashes described above in all of my apps (Hockeyapp reporting). I have no idea what I can do to resolve them, as they seem to be happening in iOS API's. They are only showing up on iOS8 devices...